# Best Practice Login With Facebook, Twitter, Google or register

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I've managed to program a login with Facebook system in my PHP webapplication. But now I'm a bit stuck in best practices.

Do I have to save the user's userID to my Database, the user's e-mail-address and/or name and surname?
I'm asking this because I'm thinking about users changing their e-mailaddress, who aren't being able to login the next time if so.

And how can I know that when a user logs in with Facebook, and the next time with Twitter for example, that it's the same user? Probably based on he's e-mail address? But I think if you haven't changed it your standard Facebook e-mail is your.name@facebook.com, right?

I'm not asking for code here, please provide me some experiences or best practices.

Comment: What you save into your database depends on what kind of data you need, and when you might need it. And no, asking for `email` permission gives you the email address the user registered to FB with (not the username@facebook.com address) – but this field might be _blank_ if they registered for FB using their mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I only need login info. And some sort of ID to store data linked to a certain user. So I guess I'll go with the e-mail field, wich is unique to a user.

Comment: Well, as I said, you might not get an email address at all – and an empty string is not unique :-)

Comment: Perhaps consider using OAuth, like StackOverflow does: then users will login using an account on some other system and you no longer need to worry about handling the authentication process.

Comment: When I use OAuth for example to login with Facebook, than I still have to store some unique key for that user, right? Or how can I recognize the user otherwise the next time?

Comment: people finding this thread from google might wanna check out https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/README.PROVIDERS.md

Comment: @hanshenrik, dead link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for me, the best practice is use [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/) library (all socials are supported it) and use database with two tables: users and users_socials.

When the users are trying to login via social, your script will create records on tables and connect this tables via "one to many" relation. All socials return unique identifier for auth user and your script can insert it onto storage for use in further.

Table scructure and test data

Table user

```
user_id   | email
________________
1         | mail@site.com
2         | 323232321@vk.com - if the social cannot return an email address
```

Table user_socials

```
social_id | user_id | social
____________________________
123213213 | 1       | facebook
332123213 | 1       | twitter
323232321 | 2       | vk
```

This pattern is good, because one user can connect many socials with his account

P.s. Facebook, Twitter, Google+ - return the user email

Comment: In my experience, "inventing" a pseudo-email address just to create a valid user record is usually indicative of a problem with the model, and is almost certainly going to cause grief at a later time. Having real data mixed in with fake data causes so many problems. If someone is allowed to create an account without an e-mail address, you should design the model that way; which means the e-mail address can't be your primary means of identification. From my point of view, `323232321@vk.com` is a really misleading subtitute for `null`. Just my two cents.

Comment: @mindplay.dk great comment. I'm trying to design around this issue atm. Do you have any suggestions or links that would help?